# Are questions about tanning on or off topic?

Tags: discussion

Gyms in my region usually offer tanning services as well and they also try to sell it as a package. They want to create the impression that a fit body also needs a good tan.

How do we handle this on F&N? Are questions about tanning suitable for this site or are they off-topic? I don't feel like it would fit well, but I am OK if other people think different, because I have a question I would ask here about tanning ;).

Comment: What is your question about tanning? The context of it would be helpful.

Comment: I generally consider tanning bad because of the skin damage. I avoid the sun during summer especially in the afternoon and I never use a tanning room. Unfortunately a brown tone looks great and makes people more attractive. I wonder if there is a level of tanning that does not damage the skin permanently and may even be healthy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe tanning is on topic for this site mainly because it is a *cosmetic* item rather than one of fitness or nutrition. I haven't heard or seen any other uses for it. I don't have any references, but I've always been under the impression that tanning isn't good for you. I don't believe that you need to be tan to be fit.

When you say:

> "Unfortunately a brown tone looks great and makes people more attractive."

it's a subjective beauty standard (generally something of the West, people in East Asia prefer light and white skin) which reinforces the notion that tanning is off-topic. [Greg's answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1972/what-can-i-do-to-make-my-abs-look-their-best-in-a-very-short-timeframe/2075#2075) to [making abdominals look their best](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1972/what-can-i-do-to-make-my-abs-look-their-best-in-a-very-short-timeframe/2075#2075) mentions tanning but as a superficial method and one that is not particularly healthy.

There was a question about [tanning without getting a burn](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3417/is-it-possible-to-get-a-tan-without-a-burn-in-one-day) that was closed. If there is a connection between fitness and tanning, then you should make that clear in the question you want to ask and what your problem and goal actually are.